# select from database where id = value from spinner

Tags: android, sql, arraylist, spinner

I have the following problem:
I have two spinners, first one with categorie1, second categorie2.

each spinner can load it's data from a database from table cat1 and cat2. But that's not exactly what I want. I want for the second spinner to load data where the cat1_id is equals cat_id from currently selected spinner1.

The tables are like this:

```
cat1:
| cat1_id | cat1_name |
=======================
| 1       | animal    |
| 2       | plant     |
| 3       | ...       |

cat2:
| cat2_id | cat1_id | cat2_name |
=================================
| 1       | 1       | fish      |
| 2       | 1       | mammal    |
| 3       | 1       | bird      |
| 4       | 2       | tree      |
| 5       | ...     | ...       |
```

How do I make this comparison or how do I know, which item is selected in spinner1.

My code is like this:

DatabaseHandler.class:

```
    public List<String> getCat(){
    labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY_CATEGORIE, null);  // SELECT_QUERY_CATEGORIE = "SELECT  * FROM  cat1";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return labels;
}

public List<String> getSubcat(){
    labels = new ArrayList<String>();
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    //cursor = db.rawQuery(SELECT_QUERY_SUBCATEGORIE, null); // SELECT_QUERY_SUBCATEGORIE = "SELECT  * FROM  cat2";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return labels;
}
```

MainActivity.class:

```
...
spCat.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spSubcat.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
loadSpinnerData();

private void loadSpinnerData() {
    List<String> lbCategorie = db.getCat();
    ArrayAdapter<String> catAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lbCategorie);
    catAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spCat.setAdapter(catAdapter);


    List<String> lbSubcategorie = db.getSubcat();
    ArrayAdapter<String> subcatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lbSubcategorie);
    subcatAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spSubcat.setAdapter(subcatAdapter);
}

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // Spinner2.Visibility should be = GONE;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Alright. I'm loading my Database now with the following code:

```
int position = MainActivity.spCat.getSelectedItemPosition()+1;
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM cat2 WHERE cat_id = ?" + position, null);
```

But my second Spinner is empty, whatever I select from the first Spinner. While debugging I noticed, that loading the database was just called once at the beginning.

---

EDIT 2:

Works now after deleting the "?" in my db.rawQuery. However the second spinner isn't it's content after changing the item in the first spinner. How do I make a refresh of the second spinner after calling the first on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Execute Query:

```
Select * From cat2 where cat1_id==cat_id
```

Comment: you mean cat1_id == cat1_id. But thats exactly my Problem. How do I know which item is selected in Spinner1?

Comment: you can get item from spinner any time by spinner.getAdapter().getItem(spinner.getSelectedPosition());

Comment: but my spinner is defined in my MainActivity.class. How can I access it from my DatabaseHandler.class ?

Comment: Pass through some method, like I assume you are calling method getSpinner2Data() to fetch second spinner data, then change method to getSpinner2Data(String id)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `catAdapter.selectedItemPosition` if the order of the items is corresponding to the categories in the table, as the selected item position starts on 0 maybe you should use `catAdapter.selectedItemPosition + 1` that way you can know what value is selected on spinner1. Also you could use something like

```
if (Integer.toString(catAdapter.selectedItem)=="1" 
{
  //put some code to tell number 1 is selected on the catAdapter
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but my second spinner is completely empty now. (check my edited question)

Comment: you might want to separate the spinner loading in 2 methods, in that way you can take the catAdapter.ItemSelected to call the second spinner loader passing the selected item to be added on your query on the second spinner loader.